# How to solve following recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations, computer-science, computational-complexity

I need to solve the following recurrence relation:

$$
\begin{align*}
T(1) &= c_1\\
T(2) &= c_2\\
T(n) &= T(\lfloor\frac{n+2}{2}\rfloor) + c_3,
\end{align*}
$$

where $c_1$, $c_2$ and $c_3$ are constants. The thing is, I really don't know how to battle the $T(\lfloor\frac{n+2}{2}\rfloor)$ part. I don't need an explicit answer, I just need to know wherever it will be logarithmic (i.e. can be upper bounded by $\mathcal{O}(\log{}n)$). I'll be glad for any ideas how to prove/disprove it.

Comment: does this happen to be about Fibonacci numbers and matrix multiplication?

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity assume $n=2^k,k\in \mathbb \{3,4,\cdots \}$. Then $$\left\lfloor\frac{n+2}{2}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}+\frac12\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{2^k}{2}+\frac12\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor2^{k-1}+\frac12\right\rfloor=\lfloor2^{k-1}\rfloor$$
So \begin{align*}
T(n)&=T(2^{k-1})+c_3=T(2^{k-2})+2c_3=T(2^{k-3})+3c_3+\cdots =T(2)+kc_3\\
&= c_2+kc_3=c_2+c_3\log n=O(\log n)
\end{align*}